# reactjs how to input multiple file from form

Tags: reactjs

I have a component like:

```
class Media extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

                    <form className="uploader" encType="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" id="file" />
                    </form>

        )
    }
}

export default Media
```

Here I want to upload multiple `file` . In `HTML` we can do it like

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

How can I have `multiple` value in `reactjs` ??
Thank you in advance

**Update**

```
class Media extends React.Component {

    handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

    render() {
        return (

                    <form className="uploader" encType="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" id="file" multiple onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                    </form>

        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Media />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here if I upload the image and the value is changed I only get first Image how to get all uploaded image ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do the same in React., you can find `attributes` which you can use [`here`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-attributes)

```js
class Media extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form
        className="uploader"
        encType="multipart/form-data"
      >
        <input type="file" id="file" multiple />
      </form>
    )
  }
}  

ReactDOM.render(
  <Media /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `multitple` might have worked before, unfortunately I’m not getting it to work in my version of ReactJS (16.8.4) - using the attribute `webkitdirectory=“true”` worked though.

```js
class Media extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form
        className="uploader"
        encType="multipart/form-data"
      >
      
      <input 
        type="file" 
        id="file" 
        webkitdirectory="true" 
       />
      
      </form>
    )
  }
}  

ReactDOM.render(
  <Media /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This forces you to select a folder.