# how to list all the files in directory using Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a folder on my machine which contains some files, so I want to access this folder and getting all of these files using reactjs

Comment: Please be more specific about the kind of files and what you intend to do with them. Also, share the code you've tried so far for the community to help you better.

Comment: see [HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reactjs how to input multiple file from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475378/reactjs-how-to-input-multiple-file-from-form)

Comment: <input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory directory /> You can upload a folder this way!